# How to move the icon to the center in this social buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am trying to move the font awesome icons to the center vertically and horizontally in its rounded background. But every time either it's on the left or on the top or on the bottom. 
How to fix those icons and move to the center?

Here is the code (Since it's in the footer I've added extra lines here in CSS):

```css
     
    .page-footer {
      background-color:#222222;
      padding: 0 40px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .page-footer a {
      font-size:14px;
      color:#ffffff;
    }
    
    ul.social-buttons {
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top:40px;
    }
    
    ul.social-buttons li a {
      font-size: 35px;
      line-height: 50px;
      display: block;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      color: #222222;
      border-radius: 100%;
      outline: none;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border:5px solid #fed136;
    }
    
    ul.social-buttons li a:active, ul.social-buttons li a:focus, ul.social-buttons li a:hover {
      background-color: #fed136;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4">

                  <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                      <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">
                          <i class=" fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">
                          <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a href="#">
                          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="list-inline-item">
                          <a href="#">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: use margin:auto

Comment: @Artyom Use `display: flex;` to `ul.social-buttons `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: @vidy that is to align horizontally not vertically. Mehraj Khan , display flex without align-items or justify-content doesn't align elements in the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align:middle` on the `i` elements. They are `inline-block` elements and they will be vertical aligned inside their container. No need to add specific line-heights or margins etc.

See below

```css
.page-footer {
  background-color: #222222;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-footer a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.social-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

ul.social-buttons li a {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #222222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 5px solid #fed136;
}

ul.social-buttons li a:active,
ul.social-buttons li a:focus,
ul.social-buttons li a:hover {
  background-color: #fed136;
}

ul.social-buttons li a i {
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
                      <i class=" fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
                    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
                      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Another option would be

```
ul.social-buttons li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` needs to be the same size as the elements container. While the `<a>` element takes up a height of `70px`, `10px` is used up by the border (`5px` each side) giving the container a height of `60px`. However, you've only used `50px` for the `line-height`.

Change the `line-height` from `50px` to `60px`.

This method just changes the `line-height` rather than using flex styles.

```css
.page-footer {
  background-color:#222222;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.page-footer a {
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
}

ul.social-buttons {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:40px;
}

ul.social-buttons li a {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #222222;
  border-radius: 100%;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border:5px solid #fed136;
}

ul.social-buttons li a:active,
ul.social-buttons li a:focus,
ul.social-buttons li a:hover {
  background-color: #fed136;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```